# OpenLDAP+Kerberos nightmare

Tags: ldap, kerberos, openldap

So for the past few weeks I've been configuring an SSO solution for our small company.
Right now I have a server running OpenLDAP 2.4.4 with kerberos (openldap backend).
Users can login and get a ticket from krb, also using SASL I can connect web applications to LDAP that will authenticate with kerberos (userPassword attribute is {SASL}user_name@MY.DOMAIN).

Everything was great, until we needed a web application for user self-service (first time account activation, password reset, etc...), after looking for some solutions I found PWM (https://github.com/pwm-project/pwm), after setting up PWM I noticed something, when trying to change a password PWM with try to write to "userPassword" attribute, but that attribute just point OpenLDAP to authenticate with kerberos.
After searching some more I couldn't find any web application that supports ldap administration with kerberos authentication, meaning an application that will change the kerberos password and not the "userPassword" attribute in OpenLDAP.
So I changed "userPassword" to hold the actual password, and with smbkrb4pwd I can synchronize the passwords in LDAP and kerberos.
Great I though, but then I realized that if I change the password in kerberos, the password in LDAP won't change, only if I change it in LDAP then smbkrb4pwd will update it in kerberos. sigh, no problem, I'll just configure PAM to use ldap for "passwd".

And today I started setting up password policies, after finishing the policy in LDAP I found out I need to create a separate one in kerberos, one can't it just use the same one in LDAP? fine.
So both password policies were working fine, accounts are being locked out after X failed attempts, great, but then I find out that if I lock my account in OpenLDAP, I can still try and authenticate in kerberos.

So here I am, totally lost on how to continue.
Is there any WEB application that knows how to change passwords in kerberos?
How can I synchronize account lock in LDAP and kerberos?

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find any web application that supports ldap administration with kerberos authentication, meaning an application that will change the kerberos password and not the "userPassword" attribute in OpenLDAP.

- See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/341332/changing-user-passwords-under-kerberos-ldap), about the overlay module to keep samba LDAP and Kerberos passwords in sync. Eg in Debian the package is called:

  "slapd-smbk5pwd - Keeps Samba and Kerberos passwords in sync within slapd."

> Is there any WEB application that knows how to change passwords in kerberos? How can I synchronize account lock in LDAP and kerberos?

- Now, there is an [App](https://www.univention.com/products/univention-app-center/app-catalog/self-service/) in Univention corporate Server UCS that enables users to change its password via a Web module. A Linux distro that make those authentication intricacies work right out of the box.

DISCLAIMER: I work for Univention =).